# Create a cmake project testing another cmake project

Tags: c++, testing, cmake

we have a cmake project which does not use automated tests. So I want to create another cmake project including the Boost-test framework to test the other project. I know, it would be perhaps better to add the test project within the other project, but we have to change the project structure for this purpose. So I want a non-invasive test project. Here is the structure of my idea:

```
   +---Project_A
          |
          CMakeList.txt
          src
          modules
          .
          .
          .
   +---Test_Project
          |
          CMakeList.txt
```

I tried to use the cmake-include statement in the Test_Project to include Project_A. But CMake tries to compile the Project_A-files within the Test_Project. So how can I tell CMake to compile the files within Project_A? Do you know maybe a better way to test Project_A without changing it's project structure?

Comment: Maybe including both your Projet_A and Test_Project directories into a parent Project_A_WithTests directorey? A CMakeFiles.txt placed in that parent directory may include both subdirectories and that would allow you to build with tests, in my opinion.

Comment: When I link the project files into this test dir, would be the links valid on other linux systems? So when another user checks out the project via SVN, would be the linked project files still available? I want to keep the project files in the test project always up to date, so the user does not have to copy the project files into the test project on every change.

Comment: Oh, you intend to add the binaries to the SVN repo. That's not a good idea. The other user should compile the sources on their own computer. Or, if not, provide binairy release packages and send that user the package.

Comment: no, that was not my idea. Each developer should only work in the original project sources and in the test project the sources should be updated automatically. I think with symbolic links this should work fine. I will try it.